# How to encrypt a database using Python and sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pysqlcipher

I've got a web app which using Flask, python3, sqlite and sqlalchemy but before I deploy I want to encrypt the contents of the database.  I've googled and read on here that pysqlcipher is the route to go (happy to choose another option if this is incorrect) but am falling down at the first hurdle:

```
pip3 install pysqlcipher3
Collecting pysqlcipher3
  Using cached pysqlcipher3-1.0.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pysqlcipher3 ... done
  Running setup.py clean for pysqlcipher3
Failed to build pysqlcipher3
Installing collected packages: pysqlcipher3
  Running setup.py install for pysqlcipher3 ... done
Successfully installed pysqlcipher3
```

Then trying in python3:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pysqlcipher3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlcipher3'
```

I can't find instructions or a simple example to get my started.  Any ideas?

Comment: web page: https://github.com/leapcode/pysqlcipher/

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  In order to use it I need to import it and that is failing.

Comment: That web page shows a different import.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but if you're saying use pysqlcipher without the 3 then it will fail because it's for 2.7 not 3.  Python 3 needs pysqlcipher3 and trying to install pysqlcipher will result in syntax errors

Comment: Hmm, https://github.com/rigglemania/pysqlcipher3 has different build instructions.

Comment: did you have intalled sqlcipher in your os??